# Java AES-128 Encryption Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I had posted this looking for help with getting this to encrypt and decrypt in Java since I use it in an Android application. I got the encryption to work but I still cannot get this to decrypt a string. Any Ideas???? Below the code is the error that I am getting.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

 private final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";    
     private final String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";    
     private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES"; 



 public String decrypt(String plainTextString, String SecretKey) throws 
     KeyException, 
     GeneralSecurityException, 
     GeneralSecurityException, 
     InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
     IllegalBlockSizeException, 
     BadPaddingException, 
     IOException{        

     byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(plainTextString, Base64.BASE64DEFAULTLENGTH);        
     byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(SecretKey);        
     return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), characterEncoding);    
     }

public  byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws 
     NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
     NoSuchPaddingException, 
     InvalidKeyException, 
     InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
     IllegalBlockSizeException, 
     BadPaddingException    {        

     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);        
     SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);        
     IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);        
     cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);        
     cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);        
     return cipherText;    
     }     

 public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws 
     NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
     NoSuchPaddingException, 
     InvalidKeyException, 
     InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
     IllegalBlockSizeException, 
     BadPaddingException    {        

     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);        
     SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);        
     IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);        
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);        
     plainText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);        
     return plainText;    
     }     

     private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{        
     byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];        
     byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes(characterEncoding);        
     System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));        
     return keyBytes;    
     }     

     public String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws 
     UnsupportedEncodingException, 
     InvalidKeyException, 
     NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
     NoSuchPaddingException, 
     InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
     IllegalBlockSizeException, 
     BadPaddingException{        

     byte[] plainTextbytes = plainText.getBytes(characterEncoding);        
     byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);        
     return Base64.encode(encrypt(plainTextbytes,keyBytes, keyBytes));    
     }
```

NETBEANS ERROR:

```
no suitable method found for decode(String,int)
    method Base64.decode(InputStream,OutputStream) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to InputStream by method invocation conversion)
    method Base64.decode(byte[],OutputStream,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Base64.decode(byte[],OutputStream) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to byte[] by method invocation conversion)
    method Base64.decode(String,OutputStream) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to OutputStream by method invocation conversion)
    method Base64.decode(String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Base64.decode(BufferedReader) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Base64.decode(byte[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Base64.decode(Element) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: Well, yes. I guess I didn't put it in that format but I am trying to just get this to work in Java. The 2 commented lines in the above code are the changes I made to the code to try to get it to work in Java from my Android App. I have not ran it since I am getting a simple "Cannot Find Symbol" error in netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tells you what the problem is.

`no suitable method found for decode(String,int)`

You can't do this

```
byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(plainTextString, Base64.BASE64DEFAULTLENGTH);
```

because it doesn't match any method signatures on `Base64`

You shouldn't use classes that start with `com.sun.*` or `sun.*` as they are internal parts of the Oracle JRE and not guaranteed to have a stable API or even be present in all JREs.

Instead, if you want a built-in class, you can use [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) and call the static method [`DataTypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29), passing your Base64 encoded String as the argument. The return value will be a `byte[]` which is what you need.

Comment: I know what the compiler is telling me. What I do not know is what I need to do to get it to work. It works fine in my Android application. A similar version using Rijndael works in my VB.net and C#.net workstation apps but here I am lost. I am missing something.

Comment: @TyJacobs The compile error has nothing to do with the cipher. Put simply `Base64.decode(String, int)` does not exist. You can't call a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: @TyJacobs It would be helpful if you could post the fully qualified class name of the `Base64` class you are using. (i.e what `Base64` class are you using)

Comment: Updated the code to inlude class and encrypt code. I just started working with Java, other than Android, on Monday. It's easy but this is kicking my rear. I have looked online, between my other apps, and in a couple other forums but for the life of me I do not see what I am missing.

Comment: @TyJacobs I updated my answer given new information about your code.